# ActiveRecord#save: `retry` breaks "autosave" for associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm overriding `save` on an ActiveRecord model in order to handle an edge case:

```rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b

  def save *args
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
    log_warning
    retry unless @foo
    throw ex
  end
end

a = A.new
a.build_b
a.save
```

And I find that when the `save` function executes for the second time (because of the `retry`), I get a MySQL error pertaining to the associated record `b`:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `bs` VALUES ()

Using a breakpoint I can see that after the `retry`, the invocation of `ActiveRecord#_create_record` ([see source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11f2bdf75a888682b34df0f9be03b94f54fc6796/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L521)) for `b` has an empty array (`[]`) for the attributes to be saved, whereas it is `["full_name","company","id","owner_id","created_at","updated_at"]` on the first invocation.

Why is `retry` breaking the auto-saving of associated records? What can I do about it?

The link above is for ActiveRecord 4.2.11.3, which is the version for the project I'm working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't override the save method, if I were you.
I would rather use the `around_save` callback.

```rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_save :saving_retry

  def saving_retry
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
    log_warning
    save unless @foo
  end
end
```